FileZilla problem connecting to earthlink but not other servers
Running Ubuntu 24.04lts, and filezilla 3.66.5. Trying to do FTP and upload webpages onto my website hosted by earthlink. I have no problem accessing FTP on my qsl.net site (other than their certificate is slightly expired...). I get this when attempting to FTP my website:
Connecting to XX.XXX.XX.X:21... (numbers obscured by me)
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status: Plain FTP is insecure. Please switch to FTP over TLS.
Status: Logged in
Status: Retrieving directory listing of "/"...
Command:    CWD /
Response:   250 CWD command successful
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 Type set to I
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (XX,XXX,XX,X,243,60)
Command:    MLSD
Error:  Connection timed out after 30 seconds of inactivity
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
Status: Disconnected from server

...and I can not get the directory "/" to load, or "/public', etc.
any ideas on why this happens? I've loaded filezilla on my WIN7 partition and same errors. Used FTPexplorer on my VISTA64 machine and it just doesn't go anywhere at all... never loads directory.
Guys w/e'link say all is ok on their end as they can run FTP w/o errors. I can use their control panel for my website via my firefox browser, and run their file manager app there, and see all is fine - upload, etc. runs fine. My ISP cut off security temporarily and we tried FTP - same error/glitch...
I've tried using gFTP and same error... darn, I'm confounded!
OK - w/sFTP:
Connecting to XX.XXX.XX.X...
Response:   fzSftp started, protocol_version=11
Command:    open "blxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com@XX.XXX.XX.X" 22
Error:  Connection timed out after 30 seconds of inactivity
Error:  Could not connect to server

...still glitches :-\
